# inject cookie using a script into localhost

Tags: javascript, html, web, cookies

due to security reasons, I have to copy cookies from the staging environment to my localhost for development purposes. I have no control over the staging environment codebase. I'm thinking of automating this process as different accounts of login might produce a different set of cookies, it frustrates me every time I do it by hand.

I'm asking is it possible to inject cookies to localhost after I logged in to the staging site? thanks.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you wanna do? Such as giving example and details will be better

Comment: @BurningAlcohol I'm asking is it possible to inject cookie to localhost after I logged in to the staging site? thanks.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, you can open the Dev Tools and paste your cookies key-value pair in `Application -> Cookies -> Your website` to inject it

Comment: @BurningAlcohol that's what I'm doing it right now, it's so tedious I have mutliple user accouts that generate different cookies

Comment: Then I think you should look into methods of XSS to yourself. Since what you are trying to do is what often referred as `cross-site cookies stealing`, that you want your localhost to "steal" the cookies from your production site, you may try to find methods in this direction.

Comment: since localhost is mine why can't I take control over it right?